# Bootstrap 4 switch change event will not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am using multiple `Bootstrap 4 switches` loaded onto the page by `JS` append and need to call a function on the switch changes. The following example works when I add the switches in `HTML`, but when I dynamically load them via `JS` after page load, it will not work.
I DO NOT want to use any other external library for this!

```
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Toggle this switch element</label>
</div>
```

I have tried multiple `JS` code, but none seems to be working. Example

```
$('.custom-control').on('change', function (e) {
  let value = this.value;
  let test = $(e).target.checked;
});
```

Also tried using the `class` of the `input` tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [checkbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox) has a checked attribute.

Hence use:

```
let test = e.target.checked;
```

Because you add dynamically the switch you need to delegate the change event:

```
$(document).on('change', '.custom-control', function (e) {
```

The snippet:

```js
$(document).on('change', '.custom-control', function (e) {
    let test = e.target.checked;
    console.log(test);
});

$('body').append('<div class="custom-control custom-switch">\
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1">\
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Toggle this switch element</label>\
</div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Just edited my question. The issue is the switches are loaded dynamically via JS

Comment: works perfectly. Thanks. Cannot accept it  as an answer yet, but will do in 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery alternatively as

```
$(document).on('change', '.custom-control', function (e) {
    let test = $(this).is(':checked');
    console.log(test);
});
```